# Sass @extend ordering - Need workaround

Tags: css, sass

Per Sass documentation:

> `@extend` works by inserting the extending selector anywhere in the stylesheet that the extended selector appears.

This is causing me great strife.  Specifically, I have Sass code from which I must extend and I do not have the liberty to modify (it's auto-generated), like so (code made up for representative example only; I understand it's not practical):

```
/* These styles cannot be updated (in a library, autogen'd, whatever) */
%base-link { color: blue }
%disabled-link { color: grey }
%hover-link { color: black }
/* End styles that cannot be updated */
```

I then have my local SCSS code:

```
/* These styles are available for modification */
a:link { @extend %base-link }
a:hover { @extend %hover-link }
a.disabled 
{
  @extend %disabled-link; 
  cursor: default;
}
```

Note that I put the `a.disabled` selector last, b/c, all else equal in terms of specificity, I want the `a.disabled` rule to trump all others (i.e. I do not want the link to turn black when a `disabled` link is hovered).

For completeness, html markup:

```
<a href="http://www.pittsburghpenguins.com">Pittsburgh Penguins</a><br>
<a href="http://www.philadelphiaflyers.com" class=disabled>Philadelphia Flyers</a><br>
```

([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLycrgrt/1/))

Proper cascading would dictate that a hyperlink with the `disabled` class should remain grey on hover (that's why I put that rule after the `hover` rule).  However, b/c Sass is moving the `extending` class to the location of the `extended` class in the stylesheet, the ordering is upended and cascading is violated.  They are effectively changing the intent of my CSS.

Is there any way to work around this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.disabled, a.disabled:hover 
{
  @extend %disabled-link; 
  cursor: default;
}
```

I think it happens cause of that `a.disabled` and `a:hover` are selectors that have equal priority. Therefore if `a.disabled:hover` isn't defined, then the rule of `a:hover` will be applied.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround.  Should have been obvious.  When in doubt, increase specificity!  For my real case, it actually worked better to add a :not(.disabled) to the :hover rule, but same idea.  

Still feels like unnecessary work to get around the fact that Sass is fundamentally changing the meaning of my styling code with this "feature."